# How to add ssh passphrase to Docker and removed it after it was used?

Tags: git, docker, security, ssh, sshpass

The problem sounds elementary in its nature but I cannot find a secure and simple solution.

The issue is the following, I have a project and I want to pull dependencies from private git repos to build a runtime environment and remove both SSH key and SSH passphrase afterward. I cannot skip passphrase as it is enforced by git remote repos.

1. I struggle to push the SSH passphrase, so the SSH won't ask for a passphrase
2. I struggle to understand how to do it securely

The question of how can I do it, so the approach also will be secure?

I am operating in Docker and potentially can install any open-source software on it.

Comment: What I generally do is drop the Passphrase, clone the repo, put the passphrase back in place. I think you made it clear that your remote has enforced the use of passphrase, so you cannot drop it and clone? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly the problem. It is enforced, so I have to overcome it. I am also not in control of the organization's policies.

Comment: I tend to run all git operations outside of Docker space.  That avoids the problem of getting a key into the image, and the possibility of leaking it; it lets me build an arbitrary branch, or working code; and it avoids trouble where Docker will not repeat a `RUN git clone` line believing it to be idempotent.

Comment: @DavidMaze It wouldn't work in my case, because the SSH connection is to build project dependencies that are in the Git. It would mean that I will need to build a project with all dependencies outside but native environments in local machine, cloud, and CI/CD pipeline may be different, so I won't use the power of Docker in that case at all. It puts usage of the Docker under questions and Docker is not something I can drop in this project.

Comment: Put the `Dockerfile` and other artifacts in the repositories themselves.  `git clone ... && docker build`.  You will still get consistent results from a consistent source tree.

Comment: With [`buildkit`](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds) enabled you can forward connections to the `ssh-agent` during the build. Clone repos i.e.: `RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git@github.com:myorg/myproject.git myproject`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [`buildkit`](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds) enabled:

> The docker build has a --ssh option to allow the Docker Engine to forward SSH agent connections.

You can `ssh-add` your private keys to a `ssh-agent`.

From the `ssh-add` `man` pages:

> If any file requires a passphrase, `ssh-add` asks for the passphrase from the user.

From the `ssh-agent` `man` pages:

> The idea is that the agent is run in the user's local PC, laptop, or terminal.  Authentication data need not be stored on any other machine, and
> authentication passphrases never go over the network.  However, the connection to the agent is forwarded over SSH remote logins, and the user can
> thus use the privileges given by the identities anywhere in the network in
> a secure way.
>
> The `ssh-agent` will never send a private key over its request channel. ...

Example `Dockerfile` from the doc:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM alpine

# Install ssh client and git
RUN apk add --no-cache openssh-client git

# Download public key for github.com
RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

# Clone private repository
RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git@github.com:myorg/myproject.git myproject
```

Build the image: `docker build --ssh default`

Comment: There is a single note to it that in Windows `default` doesn't work, so you need to specify the full pass `default=C:/.ssh/id_rsa` (or your `id_rsa` file location)

Comment: Although this is a bit off the mark, I wanted to share this documentation: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#ssh-agent-forwarding

I stumbled upon this question looking for a solution to mounting host SSH capabilities for a `docker run` command.  This doc helped!