# Clone git repo from github with dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to clone GitHub repo with below docker file after installing java,maven

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
LABEL WebAutomation Test <waaanjula@gmail.com>
RUN apk add --no-cache curl tar bash procps

# Downloading and installing Maven
# 1- Define a constant with the version of maven you want to install
ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.8.1

# 3- Define the SHA key to validate the maven download
ARG SHA=0ec48eb515d93f8515d4abe465570dfded6fa13a3ceb9aab8031428442d9912ec20f066b2afbf56964ffe1ceb56f80321b50db73cf77a0e2445ad0211fb8e38d

# 4- Define the URL where maven can be downloaded from
ARG BASE_URL=https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/${MAVEN_VERSION}/binaries

#5- Create the directories, download maven, validate the download, install it, remove downloaded file and set links
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref \
  && echo "Downlaoding maven" \
  && curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz ${BASE_URL}/apache-maven-${MAVEN_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz \
  \
  && echo "Checking download hash" \
  && echo "${SHA}  /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c - \
  \
  && echo "Unziping maven" \
  && tar -xzf /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz -C /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
  \
  && echo "Cleaning and setting links" \
  && rm -f /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz \
  && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

# 6- Define environmental variables required by Maven, like Maven_Home directory and where the maven repo is located
ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"

# # Install dependencies required to git clone.
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --update git && \
    apk add --update openssh

# 1. Create the SSH directory.
# 2. Populate the private key file.
# 3. Set the required permissions.
# 4. Add github to our list of known hosts for ssh.
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh/ 
ADD id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa 
ADD id_rsa.pub /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

RUN chmod -R 700 /root/.ssh/ && \
    touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts && \
    ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
    
RUN mkdir /usr/AutomationProject/ && \
    chmod -R 600 /usr/AutomationProject/  

# # Clone a repository (MatificWebAutomation project)
RUN git clone git@github.com:anjulaw/Selenium_Keyword_driven_Example.git /usr/AutomationProject

CMD [""]
```

and I'm getting below error

"git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists."

This is my first time using dockerfiles, but from what I have read (and taken from working configs) I cannot see why this doesn't work.

My id_rsa is in the same folder as my dockerfile and is a copy of my local key which can clone this repo no problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your ssh key needs 600 permissions to work. I recommend running the container interactively without the git clone directive and troubleshoot from there

Comment: Remember that anyone who has the image can `docker run the-image cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa` and get the private key back out.  I'd strongly recommend running the `git clone` operation outside the Dockerfile (and maybe even including the Dockerfile in the repository).

Comment: When cloning the git project it asking 'passphrase' Key, Is there any way to skip this or pass the key

Comment: Don't copy your keys into a `docker` image. [Enable `buildkit` and use your `ssh-agent` during the build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64036342/1423507).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a folder with keys in the local project folder, transfer there the generated keys that are already installed in the remote repository.

```
# SSH Keys
ADD .ssh/id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
ADD .ssh/id_rsa.pub /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa &&\
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

It turns out that after each build, the key will be generated, which means that after each build of this `Dockerfile`, you will have to reconfigure the keys on the remote repository

Comment: When cloning the git project it asking 'passphrase' Key, Is there any way to skip this or pass the key

Comment: To debugging, add after `RUN cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and check this printed key with your remote (Github or Bitbucket) ssh key in the settings profile .

Comment: resolved after generating an ssh key without passphrase